# storing old values in audit trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, row, plpgsql, audit-logging

Hi I'm developing simple audit trigger in postgres server. At the moment, I'm getting old value from name column such as below line.

```
v_old_data := ROW (OLD.name);
```

It works fine, but it store the value with parentheses. Such as `'(john)'`. Is there any way to storing/getting value from the table without parentheses?

Comment: See also http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
v_old_data := OLD.name;
```

You want the *value*, don't wrap it into a row and convert the whole row to `text` - including the parentheses that belong to the text representation of a row.